# Using STDIN with another file that use custom column separator?

Tags: awk, stdin

I have two files, with different columns in each, different separator for each file.
And I need to print only lines that $1 in `fileA` file matches $4 in `fileB` file

This will work only if both files use the same column separator:

```
cat ./fileA | awk -F' ' 'FNR==NR {lines[$4]; next} $1 in lines {print $0}' fileB -
```

**EDIT**
fileA:

```
samir x
said y
sabri z
samir y
```

fileB:

```
43,54,65,said
```

How would I use `-F` to indicate a different separator for file `fileB` ? as `fileA` uses the default space separator.

I tried:

```
cat ./fileA | awk -F' ' 'FNR==NR {lines[$4]; next} $1 in lines {print $0}' FS=',' fileB -
```

but it did not work.. any idea?

Comment: I tried before fileB and after, but I got blank result

Comment: I've just added sample content

Comment: yes its the `,`  I am experimenting this to be used with a CSV file, separated by `,`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
awk -F, 'FNR==NR { lines[$4] ; next ; } $1 in lines { print }' f2 FS=' ' f1
```

which gives

```
said y
```

Comment: Thanks, it also worked as: `cat ./f1 | awk -F, 'FNR==NR { lines[$4] ; next ; } $1 in lines { print }' f2 FS=' ' -` which what I wanted

Comment: as you like, I was trying to avoid useless use of cat. (and by the way; I didn't know before you could change `FS` in "flight").

Comment: I knew it can be changed, but I could not figure it out, thank you. As for cat, my case is that I am reading multiple access.log files, this is where `cat access.*` gets handy

Comment: @simo you can just use `awk 'script' f2 FS=' ' access.*`, no need for a UUOC then either.

Comment: Thanks @EdMorton! that's very powerful.